# Яндекс Карты Uncaught ReferenceError: ymaps is not defined at main.js:8:1 (anonymous) @ main.js:8

Tags: javascript, html, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

такая проблема, не понимаю как подключить JS файл к картам. У меня есть готовая карта, сделанная в "Конструктор Карт" от яндекса, нужно подключить ее на сайт. На сайте она отобразилась, но редактировать с помощью JS не выходит (нужно добавить панорамы и т.п), объясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как связать карту и JS файл, а то до меня не доходит. Спасибо

HTML

```
<section class="map">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="map-title">Title</h2>
    
            <div class="map-content">
                <div id="main-map" class="main-map-frame">
                    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A891ac6d60ab259e5a9247269e906cb2887e63cf533f66f9074692b71dff273a7&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=<Мой API>"></script>
                    <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

JS

```
function init() {
    let map = new ymaps.Map('main-map', {
        center:[59.089178, 37.919595],
        zoom: 19

    });
}
ymaps.ready(init);
```

JS файл лежит в папке JS, стили для карты написаны в css[image: введите сюда описание изображения]